# PHP Pascal triangle showing not properly in a table

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

I've been searching for like a few hours, but i'm not finding any solution.
I have a problem when i want to show my pascal triangle in a table, but it actually don't show properly.
Here's the code :`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Triangle de Pascal</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="POST">
            <label for="depth">Profondeur : </label>
            <input type="number" id="depth" name="depth" min="1" max="100">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <style>
            table{ 
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            td{ 
                text-align: center; 
                padding: 0px 5px; border: 1px solid black; 
                box-sizing: border-box; 
            }
        </style>
            <table>
<?php
$depth = $_POST['depth'];
$length = $depth;
$array[0][0] = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i < $depth; $i++){
    $array[$i][0] = 1;
    echo "<tr>";
        for($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++){
            if($j == $i){
                $array[$i][$j] = 1;
            }
            else{
            $array[$i][$j] = $array[$i-1][$j-1] + $array[$i-1][$j];
        }
        echo "<td colspan=".floor($length * $length / ($i)).'>'.$array[$i][$j]."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

This would be really cool if you help me to solve that problem, I don't really see where is the problem

Comment: What do you expect as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logic error in your loop, When `$j==1` you should output 1. The PHP part of your code should be something like this (i also removed some usless initialization) :

```
<?php
$depth = $_POST['depth'];
$length = $depth;
for ($i = 1; $i < $depth; $i++){
    echo "<tr>";
        for($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++){    
            if($j == 1 || $j == $i){
                $array[$i][$j] = 1;
            }
            else{
                $array[$i][$j] = $array[$i-1][$j-1] + $array[$i-1][$j];
        }
        echo "<td colspan=".floor($length * $length / ($i)).'>'.$array[$i][$j]."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Here is an example with 15 as value in your input box :

[image]